# How did this result on normal subgroups come about?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I read that given a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$, given $\{g_1,g_2\} \in G$, if $g_1K=g_2K$, it follows that for some $k \in K$, we have:

$$
g_1k=g_2
$$

I could not follow how the statement above came from the facts about normal subgroups ... The only fact I know about normal subgroups is that $gK=Kg$, but how did the above come about ?

Comment: You don't need the hypothesis that $K$ is normal. This is true for any subgroup $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g_1K = g_2K$. In particular, we have $g_2 = g_2 e \in g_2K = g_1K$. Then by the definition of $g_1K$, we may write $g_2$ as $g_1 k$ for some $k \in K$.

Comment: It's worth remarking that this is true whether or not $K$ is normal.

Comment: @Bungo $K$ need not even be a subgroup. We really only need $e\in K$